# Generate random boxed co-ordinates in c#

Tags: c#, random, coordinates

I need to find random co-ordinates, bound like a square.  For this I defined this where the values 70, 55, 175, 175 are the furthest points I want to go to:

```
north = Utility.generateRandomNumber(Utility.Directions.NORTH, 70);
south = Utility.generateRandomNumber(Utility.Directions.SOUTH, 55);
east = Utility.generateRandomNumber(Utility.Directions.EAST, 175);
west = Utility.generateRandomNumber(Utility.Directions.WEST, 175);
```

My generator is below, where I have declare a global static param:

```
public static Random random = new Random();
```

Directions is an enumerator.

```
public static int generateRandomNumber(Directions direction, int to)
{
    if ((direction == Directions.SOUTH) || (direction == Directions.WEST))
        return random.Next(to * -1, 0);
    else
        return random.Next(0, to);
}
```

The function works fine and I retrieve co-ordinates like below:

```
North: 52 South: -13 East: 82 West: -105
North: 27 South: -45 East: 172 West: -117
North: 0 South: -37 East: 161 West: -160
North: 43 South: -39 East: 26 West: -174
North: 29 South: -7 East: 75 West: -125
North: 19 South: -51 East: 93 West: -49
North: 28 South: -20 East: 26 West: -28
```

The issue is that the box is built around the (0,0,0,0) co-ordinate and I'm not sure how to get out of it whilst ensuring that North is greater than south, west is left to the map and east is right to the map.

Comment: not really sure that I understand what you are asking... " find random co-ordinates, bound like a square" so each co-ordinate denotes the side distance from the center (0,0) ? " that the box is built around the (0,0,0,0) co-ordinate" 4 dimensions?

Comment: Square is the wrong choice of shape :)  I mean that the coordinates create a boundary ... I then retrieve stuff from within that boundary.

Comment: so what exactly makes you problems? the part how to calculate that a point is within the boundaries?

Comment: @Dragonfly `Random` is not thread safe (like most things). In other words: don't make it `static`! As for your question, I don't really understand what the problem is... The way I read it a simple `random.Next(east, west);` should suffice?

Comment: @atlaste: Typically it's better to make it static but use locks to ensure serial access. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet Hmm, I can see how initializing it every call will get you into trouble :-) That said, in my experience introducing `static` will quickly lead to more pain than it solves... Thing is, both `static` and `Random` require people to understand the behavior before using it. In this case, I'd say the advice is to use the RNG over longer periods of time. Solutions include static and locking (like you propose), passing a context object around or initializing it with something that's pretty random (F.ex, using `Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()` as seed, will probably do the trick).

Comment: @atlaste: My experience is that trying to use multiple instances is much trickier than one might expect. Using a single instance, but doing so in a thread-safe manner, is the simplest approach. If you pass it around as context, it's much harder to achieve that thread-safety than if you effectively make it a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you change your approach:

- Generate a point for the North/West corner, anywhere in the appropriate range
- Generate the width and height, ensuring they're positive
- Set East = West + Width, and South = North - Height

Comment: Hi Jon, I understand your approach, mine is working fine though for me.  What I was missing is that I was generating 4 random points around a centre of (0,0,0,0).  All I needed to do is randomize that (0,0,0,0) location and set some upper and lower limits.  Thanks just the same!

Comment: @Dragonfly: But why bother putting things around a centre, if you don't need that centre coordinate for anything else?

Comment: Fair enough :)  For me was easy to generate points around a centre.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved it by randomizing also the zero coordinate.  This way the "centre" point of the bound also moved around.

Comment: Could you share your solution?